# Python - Help about For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, xpath, operating-system, lxml

I have this python code and it's working well

I'm using xpath to get the plan's title and creating a directory with this name.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import csv
import os

resp = requests.get(
                    url="https://www.architecturaldesigns.com/house-plans/prairie-style-home-plan-14469rk",
                    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Appl eWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
)

tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.text)

title = tree.xpath("//div[@class='title-text']/text()")[0]
print(title)


dirName = title.replace('\n', '')

if not os.path.exists(dirName):
    os.mkdir(dirName)
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
else:    
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")
```

I'm new at Python and I'm trying to learn For Loops...
Could someone help me to put this code on a loop?
I'm trying the following code, but it doesn't work =(

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import csv
import os

urls = ['https://www.architecturaldesigns.com/house-plans/prairie-style-home-plan-14469rk','https://www.architecturaldesigns.com/house-plans/this-plan-exudes-tradition-59348nd']

for url in urls:

resp = requests.get(
                    url=urls,
                    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Appl eWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
)

tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.text)

title = tree.xpath("//div[@class='title-text']/text()")[0]
print(title)


dirName = title.replace('\n', '')

if not os.path.exists(dirName):
    os.mkdir(dirName)
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
else:    
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")
```

I've created a list named "urls" and tried to make the for loop...
I want to put some urls in this list cuz I need that the script creates 1 directory for each url... Is it possible? Could someone help me?

Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is not entire right, the rest of the code should be run within the for loop so it does it for both urls otherwise only the last will be save and the others will be overwritten and discarded by the more recent one. So your code should actually look like this

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import csv
import os

urls = ['https://www.architecturaldesigns.com/house-plans/prairie-style-home-plan-14469rk','https://www.architecturaldesigns.com/house-plans/this-plan-exudes-tradition-59348nd']

for url in urls:

    resp = requests.get(
                    url=url,
                    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Appl eWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
    )

    tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.text)

    title = tree.xpath("//div[@class='title-text']/text()")[0]
    print(title)


    dirName = title.replace('\n', '')

    if not os.path.exists(dirName):
        os.mkdir(dirName)
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
    else:    
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")
        continue
```

Notice the change in indentation. Without this when the for loop runs, after assigning a value to title it gets overwritten by the next iteration of the loop hence by the time the for loop completes it only assigns one value and that is the last value of the iteration which means only the last value from the iteration will appear in your result. So put everything within the for loop(correct your indentation) and you should be good to go. I hope this helped

Comment: Hi @maestro.inc I really thank you, man! Now the code is running perfectly! I understand that the wrong indentation can "broke" the code. You all are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

```
for url in urls:

    resp = requests.get(
                        url=url,
                        headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Appl eWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
    )
...
```

You should use `url` instead of `urls` when calling `get()`.

Comment: Thank you @Afaq! The only problem is that the code just creates the last url in the list =( do you have any idea why that's happening? The code doesn't return any error...

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent the request.get line.

```
For url in urls:

# indent this line
  resp = requests.get(
                    url=urls,
                    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Appl eWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
)
```

Comment: ...and @Afaq is correct about using **url** instead of **urls**.

Comment: Thanks Rick! You're right, I've indented that block. The only problem is that the code just creates the last url in the list =( do you have any idea why that's happening? The code doesn't return any error...

Comment: @FranciscoSanchez you're assigning the result of `requests.get` (a `response` object) to the same variable during each iteration, so the final value of `resp` will be the result of the last iteration. If you want all of them, you either have to do something with the response in the loop as well, or store the responses in a list and then iterate the responses.

Comment: All right @b_c I think I got it... I'll try to store the data in another list. Thanks man! Let's learn...